# Do I have to pay for iAds?

Tags: iphone, iad

I am implementing iAd in my app, but I am a little confused.

If I display iAds in my app do I have to pay Apple or does Apple pay me?

Comment: you get money from apple. but don't buy the porsche yet.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt you do? I couldn't find the part of the t&cs that said that.

Comment: I hope I get some money when I reach the threshold. But at the current rate this will take until March 2013. I'll report when I have the money on my bank account.

Comment: I got answer here http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/05/adage-doesnt-like-iads-pricing-scheme/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the iAd contract that you entered into?

Have you looked it item no5 and item no6?